# Does the improper integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-xy}\sin(x)$ converge?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Does the improper integral $\large\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-xy}\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$ converge?

I know the when the integral is only on $\mathbb{R}^2_+ \times \mathbb{R}^2_+$ then it converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

However here the boundaries are different. Also it is not a positive function so I need to show it on the absolute value. It means I need to show that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-xy}|\sin(x)|\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$ converges.

I'm pretty sure it doesn't converge, since I can't bound it from the right by a converge-bale function (I tried with $e^{-xy}$, also, Wolfram Alpha said so too).

However I can't think of a function that won't converge and will bound it from the left.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: No it does not. However, it does converge on ${\mathbb{R}_+}^2\times {\mathbb{R}_-}^2$.

Comment: Can you think of a function to bound it so I can formally prove it?

Comment: look at the part $e^{-xy}$ for $y\to\infty$

Comment: Are you asking if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-xy} \sin x \, dx \, dy$ converges as iterated improper integrals or if $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-xy} \sin x$ converges as an improper integral in the sense of a limit of Riemann integrals over compact rectifiable sets $A_n$ where $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ and $\cup_n A_N = \mathbb{R}^2$?  You have to be careful about how an improper multiple integral is defined.

Comment: As far as iterated integrals are concerned -- how could $\int_0^\infty e^{-xy} \sin x \, dx$ possibly converge if $y < 0$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To begin, the function $(x,y) \mapsto e^{-xy} \sin x$ is not absolutely integrable.  It is enough to show this for the region $[0,\infty)^2$.

If it were then we could apply Fubini's theorem to the iterated integrals and conclude

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-xy} | \sin x| \, dx \, dy = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-xy} | \sin x| \, dy \, dx $$

However,

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-xy} | \sin x| \, dy= \frac{|\sin x|}{x} $$

and this is neither Lebesgue nor improperly Riemann integrable over  $[0,\infty]$.

The question seems to be is the improper Riemann integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f$ convergent, where $f(x,y) = e^{-xy} \sin x$.

For integrals over $\mathbb{R}$ the definition of an improper integral as $\lim_{a \to -\infty, b \to +\infty}\int_a^b f$  is unambiguous. For multiple integrals the definition of improper integral requires more care.  The standard is

$$\tag{*}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f = \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{A_n}f,$$

where $A_n$ is an admissible sequence, that is a sequence of compact Jordan measurable sets such that $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ for all $n$ and $\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \mathbb{R}^2$.

For the improper integral to be well defined, (*) must hold for any admissible sequence with convergence to a unique value. This has an important consequence:

> If $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f$ converges as an improper integral in the
>   sense of (*) then $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |f|$ converges.

See [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/i326659) for a proof.

Since  $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-xy} |\sin x|$ does not converge it follows that the improper integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-xy} \sin x$ does not converge in the sense of (*).  In fact, it can take on different values depending on exactly how the limiting process is defined.  This is analogous to the problem with rearrangements of conditionally convergent infinite series. An example is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2138663/148510).