# What is the definition of improper multi-variable integral with combination of unlimited integral area and infinity function value??

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

For example in $R^2$ with area $D=(a,\infty)\times(b,\infty)$

Function $f(x,y)$ is defined on $(x,y)\in D$

And $x=a,y=b$ are branch points, which means $\forall y\in(a,\infty)\Rightarrow\lim_{x\to a}f(x,y)=\infty$ and $\forall x\in(a,\infty)\Rightarrow\lim_{y\to b}f(x,y)=\infty$

What would the official definition of improper integral on area $D$ converges??

---

To further illustrate the concept, I may list some more information here:

The formal definition I got for a 2-dimension improper integral with unlimited integration area are as this:

Suppose $D\in R^2$ is an unlimited area. There is a line $\Gamma\in D$ separate $D$ into a limited part $D_\Gamma$ and unlimited part. Say a point $(x,y)\in\Gamma$ we define $d(\Gamma)=\inf\left\{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\big|(x,y)\in\Gamma\right\}$

So the definition is when $d(\Gamma)\to\infty$ **disrespect of what kind of $\Gamma$ you choose**, $\lim_{d(\Gamma)\to\infty}\int_{D_\Gamma}f(x,y)dxdy$ always converge, thus we have $\int_{D}f(x,y)dxdy=\lim_{d(\Gamma)\to\infty}\int_{D_\Gamma}f(x,y)dxdy$

Here the key point is, $\Gamma$ can be any shape.

So the formal definition of this would be $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta$, for all $\Gamma$ that satisfy:

1. $D_\Gamma$ is limited
2. $d(\Gamma)>\delta$

We have $\left|\int_{D_\Gamma}f(x,y)dxdy-I\right|<\epsilon$

Thus we can say $\int_{D}f(x,y)dxdy=I$

This also brings up the key thing that the convergence of $\int_{D}|f(x,y)|dxdy$ is a sufficient and necessary condition of $\int_{D}f(x,y)dxdy$ converges (in 1-detention, $\int_{D}f(x,y)dxdy$ converges does not support $\int_{D}|f(x,y)|dxdy$ converges).

Because you could choose any shape of $\Gamma$, thus for periodic function (Which do has limit say  $|f(x,y)|<M$), I can select $\Gamma$ that contains all the positive area and with size of negative area as $\frac{1}{M}$.

Comment: Thanks @erictowers corrected~~lol

Comment: Don't you mean $\forall y \in (b,\infty)$?  Also, maybe you mean singularity or point of discontinuity.  It's weird to have continuum many branch points (though not impossible).

Comment: Hi @erictowers say if $f(x,y)=\frac{e^{-x-y}}{x^{0.5}y^{0.5}}$ that is for all value of given $y\in(0,\infty)$ the limitation of $x\to0$ of the function is infinity. Sorry for my terrible expression............. hope I can explain things clearer..

Comment: In your example in comments, you have (infinite) singularities at every point of the coordinate axes.

Comment: hmmm, I got this question when trying to prove of relationship of Gamma function and Beta function, which indicated that $\beta(p,q)=\frac{\Gamma(p)\Gamma(q)}{\Gamma(p+q)}$

Comment: Riemann, Lebesgue, or other?

Comment: Riemann........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be an open set. If $D$ is unbounded and/or $f:D \to \mathbb{R}$ is unbounded at the boundary, then the improper (Riemann) integral has to be carefully defined and there can be problems as you suspect if we don't have convergence of the improper integral of $|f|$ under the definition.

First, we require that $f$ be Riemann integrable over any compact $A \subset D$ which is also rectifiable (measure of boundary is $0$).

We can define the improper integral over $D$ by selecting any sequence $(A_n)$ of compact rectifiable sets which are nested in the sense that $A_n \subset \text{int}(A_{n+1})$ and which exhaust $D$, meaning $D = \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. Defining $f^+ = \max (f,0)$ and $f^- = \max(-f,0)$ the improper integral is

$$\int_D f = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} f^+ - \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} f^- ,$$

when both limits exist. In this way $|f| = f^+ + f^-$ must also have a convergent improper integral.  It can be shown that the improper integral is independent of the choice of $(A_n)$ provided the above conditions are met.

If we find only conditional convergence

$$I_{\mathcal{A}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} f^ ,$$

for a specific sequence $\mathcal{A} = (A_n)$ then there is no guarantee that we will get the same result for another choice of sets.

This is true even in the one-dimensional case as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2138689/148510).

Comment: Hi thanks very much. I may understand it like this, the improper integral overall can be defined as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\cup_{n=1}^n An}f(\vec{x})d\vec{x}=I$  if $\{A_n\}$ satisfy $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cup_{n=1}^n An=D$ , is that right??

Comment: @Shore:  As long as $\int_{A_n} |f|$ converges as $n\to \infty$ for some sequence of nested compact sets where $\cup_{n \geqslant 1}A_n = D$ then it converges for any such sequence to the same value and the sequence $\int_{A_n} f $ will also converge to that value which we can define as the improper integral.  Without that absolute convergence we may have conditional convergence for a particular sequence but possibly not for other sequences.

Comment: In the linked answer I show that the improper integral $\int_0^{\infty} \sin(x)/x \,dx = \lim_{c \to \infty} \int_0^c \sin(x)/x\, dx = \pi/2$ is the common definition of the improper integral but because it is not absolutely convergent other definitions using exhaustive sets can give different answers.

Comment: in 2D you have to worry about how to define the improper integral when there is conditional convergence. Recall that even if you can set up the double integral as iterated integrals you can get different values if you switch the order of integration, unless there is absolute convergence and Fubini’s theorem holds.

Comment: Thank you very much~~

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be "The 
$$  \lim_{(L,R,B,T) \rightarrow (a,\infty,b,\infty)}\iint_{[L,R]\times[B,T]} \dots \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}y  $$ exists."

Your characterization of the boundary is a little unusual, so I may be misinterpreting it.  You seem to be saying the integrand is undefined on the set $(\{a\}\times [b,\infty)) \cup ([a,\infty) \times \{b\})$, so the left edge and bottom edge of the rectangle of integration must approach these rays in the limit.

Comment: Well I think this may cause some problem, the thing is, if I define an periodic function such as $\sin(x^2)$ and limit the area as $[0,\infty)\times(0,1)$ the improper integral of $\int_D\sin(x^2)dv$ exists and $\int_D|\sin(x^2)|dv$ actually divergence. So it actually breaks the absolute condition of integrable of multivariate improper integration

Comment: @Shore : Nothing in your Question specifies periodicity or integrability.  It seems that your problem specification is incomplete.

Comment: Sorry for my improper expression, but this is the problem. In multivariate improper integration, the integrable of absolute value of the function is  necessary and sufficient condition of integrable of the function

Comment: The definition of the existence of the improper Riemann integral (regardless of number of variables) is that the limit I wrote in my answer exists.

Comment: That sustain for 1 dimension integral, but here is multivariate integral. Actually it will separate the region of integration and sum it. The basic idea is the same........

Comment: @Shore : I am unable to guess what you mean.  What I have written is the specialization of the definition of multivariable improper integral to the case of two dimensions, as specified in your problem statement.

Comment: Hi @erictowers, I updated my question and further illustrated more. I think simply using $(L,R,B,T)→(a,\infty,b,\infty)$ is kind of not right. As I specified in my question, the key is that the cutting line can be any shape, as long as it satisfy certain condition. Sorry to reply you so late since I was busy yesterday........